# How do you zoom out favicon.ico in vscode editor?

Tags: visual-studio-code, favicon

There is only zoom in option when opening a `favicon.ico` or `.ico` format in vscode. How to zoom this out. It looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is zoom out percentage at the blue bar down at the bottom right side.

[image]

Clicking on that will restore it back to 100%.